# Simple POST with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have two ASP.NET Core 2.1 apps and I'm trying to make a simple `POST` call from one app to the other using `HttpClient`.

For some reason, when I use `[FromBody]` to get the simple text I'm trying receive, I get a `BadRequest` error.

Here's my code on the sender. First, this is what's in my `ConfigureServices` method. I'm using the new `HttpClientFactory` feature in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I also created a client class named `myApiCallerClient` that handles my API calls:

```
services.AddHttpClient("myNamedClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50625/api/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
});

services.AddScoped(x => {
   var httpClientFactory = x.GetRequiredService<System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory>();
   var myApiCallerClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("myNamedClient");
   return new Clients.ApiCaller.ApiCallerClient(myApiCallerClient);
});
```

Here's the code in myApiCallerClient:

```
public async Task SayHello()
{
     var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("test", new StringContent("Saying hello!", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"));
}
```

And here's my code on the receiving end which is the `POST()` API method in `TestController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post([FromBody]string input)
{
    // Some logic
}
```

My call doesn't hit this method if I use `[FromBody]` and I get `BadRequest` error on the sender. If I use `[FromHeader]` my request hits this API method but I'm getting a `null` value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's definitely showing `BadRequest`. You said you expect `415`. What are you seeing that is not correct?

Comment: Ultimately I won't be sending text. My main concern here is that I'm not hitting my API method. Do you think I'm not hitting it because of `Content-Type`? Once I make sure everything is working, I'll be sending `JSON` data which will get deserialized on the receiving end.

Comment: Yes, I do. You can easily test it by changing your `HttpClient` request to use `application/json` instead of `text/plain` and simply add surrounding quotes to your dummy string (`"\"Saying hello!\""`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET Core doesn't support a `Content-Type` of `text/plain` out of the box, so the server is rejecting your request as it's not something that it can parse when using the `[FromBody]` attribute.

In the comments, you said:

> Ultimately I won't be sending text. My main concern here is that I'm not hitting my API method. [...] Once I make sure everything is working, I'll be sending JSON data which will get deserialized on the receiving end.

In order to test whether the problem is due to the `text/plain` `Content-Type`, you can update your `PostAsync` line to something like this:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(
    "test",
    new StringContent("\"Saying hello!\"", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

As `application/json` *is* a supported `Content-Type` by default, the code above uses that and wraps the value you were sending with `"`s in order to make it a valid JSON value.